# discrete version of $L_p$

Tags: normed-spaces

Why is $(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}e^{-px_i/\epsilon}\bar{h}_i)^{1/p}=O(N^{-1/p})$,as $N$ approaches 0, where $\bar{h}_i=(h_{i+1}+h_i)/2$, $h_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$? The integral version is much easier to calculate.